# problemas de programación en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

hola alguien tiene conocimientos sobre wordpress? a ver si alguien me da su punto de vista, tengo el siguiente codigo en una template es muy facil por que en cierta parte funciona, las variables post las extraigo de un js la cual si las muestra en pantalla la veo con el "echo" y aparece todo eso lo actualizo con un div donde ya tengo asociado este php y si las actualiza cada vez que escojo una opcion diferente y las muestra y las cambia, el problema esta que necesito mostrar un ejemplo ids donde la variable 1 es un tag, pero no las muestra aunque en el array el tag y ponga el valor de la variable ni poniendola manual ni nada, lo curioso que he intentado poner html y otro codigo y si me lo respeta pero esto no, y si mando a mostrar mi php como tal sin el proceso si me extrae toda las id del tag por eso se que igual el codigo del array donde extraigo los post funciona, pero cuando lo hago con todo y función no.

```
<?php  
 $variable1= $_POST["variable1"];
 $variable2= $_POST["variable2"];
 $variable3= $_POST["variable3"];
 echo $variable1;
  if ($variable1!== null ):
  global $post;
  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'nombres',
   'post_parent' => 0,
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'nopaging' => true,
   'orderby' => 'menu_order',
   'order' => 'DESC'
        );  
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            
            while ( $query->have_posts() ): 
            
            $query->the_post();
            $post = get_post(); 
            $post_tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
            
    ?>
    <?php echo $post->ID;  ?>
    <?php endwhile?>
    <?php endif?>
```

Comment: Es algo confuso lo que intentas explicar. Cuando `$variable1` contiene un post tag quieres que se muestren solamente los posts asociados a ese post tag?

Comment: **"a ver si alguien me da su punto de vista"** las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas.